# Exploratory question on fortran to python/numpy

Tags: fortran, f2py

this question is very exploratory as I have been looking for an answer but coming up empty I just need help focusing on what area to explore to solve my problem, so here goes my explanation.

I have a large Fortran 90 codebase project with a makefile that has one central file called RunModel (IE the file that calls all other files and opens output files is called RunModel.f90). So all thise files .f90 compile and link into RunModel.out. What I would like to do to make the program more accessible to grad students to modify/add to is make a python file RunModel.py that instantiates all the arrays (real and integer) that RunModel.f90 does and runs all the fortran routines in the supporting fortran files.

so my plan was use f2py RunModel.f90 + all the other f90 in the make file project to make an importable library for python 3.x 
then using numpy build out the arrays and matrices in python in RunModel.py not RunModel.f90 and in the py file import the compiled/f2py code and just run them all from the new RunModel.py.

does that sound feasible? will numpy arrays and matrices act the same way as the FORTRAN arrays do?

sorry for the vagueness , like I said I am just fishing for the moment.

Comment: Not an expert on this but it's definitely feasible.  In a nutshell you just convert the main program into a subroutine and then import that.  How easy is this?  Depends on your code and may need some trouble-shooting along the way, but for sure doable.

Comment: Regarding numpy arrays, I'm pretty sure they default to C order rather than Fortran, but numpy has lots of facilities for handling this.  This won't be a problem in any way.

Comment: You also might want to consider numpy's tofile & fromfile which lets you read and write binary files that can easily be read into fortran (or c).  For me this is the generally easiest way to go between Fortran and numpy (or sas or stata)

Comment: OK I am still peeling this f2py onion right now the main program RunModel.F calls all the other routines in other files. So the key is to make the RunModel.F be a place where all the called routines are just defined then when f2py(ed) they will become a python module that i can "import" ? Is that correct?